# Responsive Size only working on debug mode not Design view on Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio, parameters, size

Can someone give me a hand?

I'm new on c# and currently working on my own project, but I kinda confused when I try to make the screen responsive, but at the ends, it only affects when it's run in debug mode and for the design view visual studio it's remained same. Is there any way to fix this?

At any rate, I'm sorry for taking your time and thank you.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you're suggesting, but it sounds like maybe you have locked your design window size?

Try right clicking on your application in design view and check if "Lock controls" is enabled.